# Load repeated elements from an XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I am looking to load repeated elements from an XML file I have called `initialInspections.xml`. The problem is that the system needs to be dynamic and to allow as many different `inspectionNotes` to be added. I need to input all of them even though they have the same name.

If someone could please give me a method of doing this I would be extremely appreciative, since I have been searching for almost 3 hours now and I haven't found anything that works.

I need all off the data from within each `inspectionNote` node, and it will be put into an array of a structure called `initialInspectionNotes`.

Here is what I have up to now:

```
    public int propertyID;
    public string initialInspectorUsername;
    public DateTime intialDateTime;
    public struct initialInspectionNotes
    {
        public string locationWithinProperty;
        public string locationExtraNote;
        public string costCode;
        public float estimatedTime;
    }
    private void finalInspection_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Open the intialInspections xml file and load the values into the form
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        FileStream rFile = new FileStream(values.xmlInitialFileLocation, FileMode.Open);
        xdoc.Load(rFile);
        XmlNodeList list = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("initialInspection");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            XmlElement initialInspection = (XmlElement)xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("initialInspection")[i];
            XmlElement initialInspector = (XmlElement)xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("userInspection")[i];
            XmlElement dateTime = (XmlElement)xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("dateTime")[i];
            propertyID = int.Parse(initialInspection.GetAttribute("propertyID"));
            initialInspectorUsername = initialInspector.InnerText;
            intialDateTime = DateTime.Parse(dateTime.InnerText);
        }
        rFile.Close();
    }
```

The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<initialInspections>
    <initialInspection propertyID="1">
        <userInspection>defaultadmin</userInspection>
        <dateTime>07/11/2015 17:15:20</dateTime>
        <inspectionNote>
            <location>Dining Room</location>
            <locationNote>Remove whole carpet, leave underlay</locationNote>
            <CostCode>L1</CostCode>
            <estimatedTime>5</estimatedTime>
        </inspectionNote>
        <inspectionNote>
            <location>Other - See Notes</location>
            <locationNote>On the marked area with orange spray paint.</locationNote>
            <CostCode>B1</CostCode>
            <estimatedTime>12</estimatedTime>
        </inspectionNote>
    </initialInspection>
</initialInspections>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: go to this site here to validate your XML file.. it has some errors you need to fix these XML errors first. http://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidate also what are you doing with this `public struct initialInspectionNotes` I personally would create that as a `class` then I would create a `var lstNotes = new List<initialInspectionNotes>()` then in your loop populate the fields making sure that you add to a different List<T> the lstNotes objects inside of the loop using the new construct at the top of the loop and the .Add method of the List<T> at the bottom of the loop

Comment: I am going to edit you question with why you should change your XML to in order for it to work based on the `validate XML` free online

Comment: @MethodMan I just ran my file through that website and it said it was fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to use the [LINQ2XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) and the [LINQ Descendants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to fetch all `inspectionNotes` at once:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(fileLocation); // for example c:\temp\input.xml
// fetch all inspectionNotes
var inspectionNotes = xml.Root.Descendants("inspectionNote").ToList();
// TODO: error handling!
// map inspectionNote node to custom structure
var arrayOfNotes = inspectionNotes.Select (n => new initialInspectionNotes
{
    costCode = n.Element("CostCode").Value,
    estimatedTime = float.Parse(n.Element("estimatedTime").Value),
    locationExtraNote = n.Element("locationNote").Value,
    locationWithinProperty = n.Element("location").Value,
})
// and convert the result to array holding elements of the custom structure
.ToArray();
foreach (var note in arrayOfNotes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(note.locationExtraNote);
}
```

The output is:

```
Remove whole carpet, leave underlay
On the marked area with orange spray paint.
```

Same logic applies if you want to read and map another XML nodes (f.e. `initialInspection`).

---

If you need to use `XmlReader` then use [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) in order to fetch the inner `inspectionNote` elements and the values of every `inspectionNote` element, using [XmlNode.SelectSingleNode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [XmlNode.SelectNodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
   //Open the intialInspections xml file and load the values into the form
   XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
   FileStream rFile = new FileStream(values.xmlInitialFileLocation, FileMode.Open);
   xdoc.Load(rFile);
   XmlNodeList list = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("initialInspection");
   // create list of initialInspectionNotes in order to add as many nodes as needed
   var notes = new List<initialInspectionNotes>();
   // map data
   for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
   {
       // read data
       XmlElement initialInspection = (XmlElement)xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("initialInspection")[i];
       XmlElement initialInspector = (XmlElement)xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("userInspection")[i];
       XmlElement dateTime = (XmlElement)xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("dateTime")[i];
       propertyID = int.Parse(initialInspection.GetAttribute("propertyID"));
       initialInspectorUsername = initialInspector.InnerText;
       intialDateTime = DateTime.Parse(dateTime.InnerText);
       // fetch notes!
       var inspectionNotes = initialInspection.SelectNodes("inspectionNote");
       foreach (XmlNode inspectionNote in inspectionNotes)
       {
            // insert data into list
            notes.Add(new initialInspectionNotes
                                {
                                    locationExtraNote = inspectionNote.SelectSingleNode("locationNote").InnerText,
                                    costCode = inspectionNote.SelectSingleNode("CostCode").InnerText,
                                    locationWithinProperty = inspectionNote.SelectSingleNode("location").InnerText
                                });
       }
   }
   // convert to array if needed
   //var arrayOfNotes = notes.ToArray();
   rFile.Close();
```

Regardless of how many `inspectionNote` elements the XML contains, the list resp. array will read them all.

Comment: Thanks for this, it was exactly what I needed :)

Comment: Glad that the answer helped.

Comment: Ok, So I seem to actually be getting an error as soon as it reaches the notes.Add line. System.ArgumentNullException It seems like no actual values are being loaded by the code and it is just erring out when it hits that line.

Comment: I actually seem to get the error because inspectionNote.SelectSingleNode(...).Value isn't returning anything.

Comment: This means that there are XML nodes missing some subnodes (for example missing `<location>`). Check your XML. Debug your code - step by step. Add error handling and default values. Extract the `SelectSingleNode(...)` code to a function that returns a default value if the value is `null`.

Comment: but none of the values are null. As you can see in the xmlFile all of the values are populated yet it is still returning null every time no matter what I do. I am very grateful for the help, however nothing seems to be working at this point.

Comment: I have overlook the results. You are correct. Sorry. Change the `.Value` property with `InnerText` and it will work - `locationExtraNote = inspectionNote.SelectSingleNode("locationNote").InnerText`.

Comment: Thanks so much, I have been tearing my hair out for the past 3 hours trying to do this. It now (FINGERS CROSSED) works, it didn't crash and it actually loaded the correct amount of values into the list. Thanks for all your help dude, first time using stack overflow and I have to say it was definitely worth signing up :)

Answer (score 3):

```
class Note
{
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string LocationNote { get; set; }
    public string CodeCost { get; set; }
    public string EstimatedTime { get; set; }
}

var xml = XElement.Load(...your xml path here );

var data = xml.Descendants("initialInspection").Elements("inspectionNote").Select(n => new     Note()
{
    Location = n.Element("location").Value,
    LocationNote = n.Element("locationNote").Value,
    CodeCost = n.Element("CostCode").Value,
    EstimatedTime = n.Element("estimatedTime").Value

}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class InitialInspectionNotes
{
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string LocationNote { get; set; }
    public string CodeCost { get; set; }
    public string EstimatedTime { get; set; }
}

var xdoc = XDocument.Load("yourpath\filename.xml");

var dataXml = xdoc.Descendants("initialInspection").Elements("inspectionNote").Select(n => new InitialInspectionNotes()
{
    Location = n.Element("location").Value,
    LocationNote = n.Element("locationNote").Value,
    CodeCost = n.Element("CostCode").Value,
    EstimatedTime = n.Element("estimatedTime").Value

}).ToList();

var xmlList = new List<object>();
for (int i = 0; i < dataXml.Count; i++)
{
    xmlList.Add(dataXml[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite all the answers above might have worked, I have however found it quite complicated for reading just elements. I found a simpler solution which I would like to share for future audience in this case.

Supposing you have read the document stream into `XmlDocument` object named as `document`.

```
var dataNodes = document.GetElementsByTagName("Data");

var toList = dataNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().ToList();
```

In my case, `Data` node was not being called repeatedly. Hence this works, now I was able to append multiple nodes with the same name.